# Alternative to Binomial Test for Hypothesis Testing with Low Sample Size in Python

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, multiple-regression, python

I am working with a dataset where I aim to test the hypothesis that a specific group behaves differently than expected across different conditions. I am assuming that if this group behaves differently, this behavior is consistent across all conditions.

For each condition, I have a separate sample. For instance, the theoretical frequency of a certain behavior under condition A is 25%, but in my data, the actual frequency for the group is 114 times out of 323 samples. Under condition B, the theoretical frequency is 33%, actual frequency is 33 times out of 100 samples. Under condition C, the theoretical frequency is 37.5%, actual frequency is 4 times out of 20 samples.

I am looking to test this hypothesis using Python and aim for a significance level of 0.05. I am interested in a method that provides a p-value for the aggregate of all samples. However, due to the low sample size for each subsample (e.g., only 20 samples for condition C), I do not want to use a binomial test.

I have attempted to use a Chi-Squared test, but I am uncertain if it is appropriate for this scenario. Here is the code I used:

````
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

observed_frequencies = np.array([114, 33, 4])
expected_frequencies = np.array([323*0.25, 100*0.33, 20*0.375])
chi2, p_value, _, _ = chi2_contingency([observed_frequencies, expected_frequencies])

print(p_value) # 0.17090289419933605
```
````

Answer (score 1):

your question is more like a multi-group test for given proportions. As far as I know, python doesn't seem to have such a function in scipy.stat, or stat.model. In R, you can simply use this.

```r
observed_frequencies = c(114, 33, 4)
tot_counts = c(323, 100, 20)
expected_prop = c(0.25, 0.33, 0.375)
prop.test(x = observed_frequencies, n = tot_counts, p = expected_prop)
```

result is this

```
        3-sample test for given proportions without continuity correction

data:  observed_frequencies out of tot_counts, null probabilities expected_prop
X-squared = 20.868, df = 3, p-value = 0.0001121
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
null values:
prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 
 0.250  0.330  0.375 
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3 
0.3529412 0.3300000 0.2000000
```

if you stick on python, you can try r2py

```py
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
stats = importr('stats')

observed_frequencies = np.array([114, 33, 4])
tot_counts = np.array([323, 100, 20])
expected_prop = np.array([0.25, 0.33, 0.375])

prop = stats.prop_test(x = observed_frequencies, n = tot_counts, p = expected_prop)

print(prop)
```

or you can calculate it by hand.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
observed = np.array([114, 33, 4, 323 - 114, 100 - 33, 20 - 4]) # observed success and failed count
expected = np.array([323 * 0.25, 100 * 0.33, 20 * 0.375, 323 * (1.0 - 0.25), 100 * (1.0 - 0.33), 20 * (1.0 - 0.375)]) # expected success and failed count
chisq = np.sum((np.abs(observed - expected)) ** 2 / expected)
pvalue = 1.0 - scipy.stats.chi2.cdf(chisq, df = 3)
print(f"chisq: {chisq:.3f}, p value: {pvalue:.7f}")
# or scipy.stats.chisquare(observed, expected, ddof=3-1)
# chisq: 20.868, p value: 0.0001121
```

reference:

[Hypothesis Testing towards multi-group proportion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/506233/hypothesis-testing-towards-multi-group-proportion)

Comment: scipy has a native function to do that: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html . Note that the question is apparently a duplicate of this one https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/628635/testing-the-hypothesis-of-differences-in-expected-and-observed-frequencies-in-a , in the discussion in the comment section @mdewey suggested a chi-squared goodness-of-fit like you did, but unfortunately OP did not give any feedback relative to it. Hopefully your answer should answer her question if she didn't see mdewey suggestion!

Comment: Yes, it's better to edit to clarify or add detail, & get the q. re-opened @MariaTorres. One point that was emphasized more in the original, with its discussion of under- & over-bluffing, was that the alternative against which you want your test to have power is that either the true probabilities are higher than expected across all conditions, or the true probabilities are lower than expected across all conditions.